# Why does a flat degeneration induce equality in the K-Theory?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ be two closed subschemes of a smooth, complex, algebraic variety $X$. We will be interested in the Grothendieck ring of coherent sheaves of $X$, i.e. isomorphism classes of such sheaves modulo exact sequences and a product given by the tensor product of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules.

Denote by $[\mathcal{O}_{Z_1}]$ the class of $f^\ast\mathcal{O}_{Z_1}$ in the Grothendieck Ring of coherent sheaves on $X$, where $f:Z_1\to X$ is the inclusion.

Assume now that $Z_2$ is a flat degeneration of $Z_1$, i.e. there is a morphism $\pi: Y\to \mathbb{A}^1$ of schemes such that the generic fiber of $\pi$ is isomorphic to $Z_1$ and the fiber of $\pi$ over $0$ is isomorphic to $Z_2$.

I am reading a paper by David Speyer with the title 
*"A matroid invariant via the K-theory of the Grassmannian"* and on page 885, right below equation (3) he says that $[\mathcal{O}_{Z_1}]=[\mathcal{O}_{Z_2}]$ holds in this case. I don't see how to prove this implication and I'd be very grateful if someone could explain it to me.

Comment: Something wrong here. Maybe you want $Y\subset X\times \Bbb{A}^1$ ?

Comment: @abx: Frankly, I looked up the definition of "flat degeneration", that term appears without further explanation in the paper. Maybe it means what you say in this context?

Comment: Definitely $Y \subset X \times \mathbb A^1$, i.e. $Y$ is not just a flat family but a flat family _of subschemes._ They way you state it would include things like $Z_1,Z_2$ a line and conic in the plane, isomorphic but not $K$-equivalent.

Comment: I don't understand why this is a ring. Tensoring with a sheaf does not preserve exact sequences, unless it is a vector bundle. Am I missing something?

Comment: @HailongDao: The tensor product does define a multiplication in the free abelian group on the isomorphism classes of coherent sheaves. Hence, it still defines a multiplication after dividing out by the exactness relation. Maybe [this question on math.se](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912480/definition-of-multiplication-in-grothendieck-ring) can clarify a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Allen says, we are talking about flat subfamilies of $X$. I.e. $Y$ is a closed subscheme of $X \times \mathbb{A}^1$, flat over $\mathbb{A}^1$, with $Z_0 \times \{ 0 \}$ and $Z_1 \times \{ 1 \}$ the fibers over $0$ and $1$.

Replacing $Y$ by its closure in $X \times \mathbb{P}^1$, we may assume that we instead have $Y$ closed in $X \times \mathbb{P}^1$, flat over $\mathbb{P}^1$. (Since $\mathbb{P}^1$ is smooth and one dimensional, being flat over it just means all associated primes of $Y$ map to the generic point of $\mathbb{P}^1$.)

On $\mathbb{P}^1$, we have short exact sequences
$$0 \to \mathcal{O}(-1) \to \mathcal{O} \to k_0 \to 0$$
and 
$$0 \to \mathcal{O}(-1) \to \mathcal{O} \to k_1 \to 0$$
where $k_0$ and $k_1$ are the skyscraper sheaves of a point at $0$ and $1$ respectively. So the point $0$ and the point $1$ have the same class in $K_0(\mathbb{P}^1)$. Since $Y \to X$ is flat, we can pull this back to an equality $[\mathcal{O}_{Z_0}] = [ \mathcal{O}_{Z_1}]$ on $Y$.

Since $Y$ is closed in $X \times \mathbb{P}^1$, the map $\pi: Y \to X$ is proper and we can push forward this equality to $X$. We need to check that $\pi_{\ast} \mathcal{O}_{Z_i \times \{ i \}} = \mathcal{O}_{Z_i}$ and $R^j \pi_{\ast} \mathcal{O}_{Z_i \times \{ i \}} =0$ in order to know that the $K$-theoretic push forward is the obvious thing.

I'm not sure where to cite this argument to, it is something that everyone I talked to about this sort of thing seemed to view as obvious. Allen does the analogue for equivariant $K_0$, which is more interesting, in Prop 3.5 of his [recent paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.1261).