# Do almost commutative flat degenerations induce equality in K-theory? (Or: Is the characteristic variety actually a support of a class in $K$-theory?)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology, noncommutative-geometry, noncommutative-algebra, d-modules

I intentionally phrased the title to match a [different question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186367/why-does-a-flat-degeneration-induce-equality-in-the-k-theory) which is almost identical to the one i'm asking. However similar, the answer there, which uses commutative algebraic geometry, is not directly applicable here as the setting is non-commutative.

Let $A$ be an almost commutative algebra over a field $k$. Meaning $A$ is a ($\mathbb{N}$-)filtered associative algebra whose associated graded $grA$ is commutative. There's a flat degeneration from $A$ to $grA$ which goes by the name of "Rees algebra". This is the graded algebra $R=\oplus_{n \ge0} t^n F_nA$. We may view this geometrically as follows:

Consider "$SpecR$" as a flat family over $\mathbb{A}^1_k$. The fiber over $0$ is $Spec(grA)$ while the rest of the fibers are isomorphic to "$SpecA$".

The only example I have in mind is the algebra of differential operators on an smooth affine scheme $X$ in char $0$. In that case $A=\mathcal{D}_X$ and $Spec(grA)= T^*X$. The notion of good filtration has a natural interpretation in this picture:

> A good filtration on a coherent $\mathcal{D}_X$-module $\mathcal{M}$ is the same as the data of an $R$-module $\mathcal{N}$ with an isomorphism $\mathcal{N} \otimes_R R[t^{-1}] \cong \mathcal{M} \otimes_{\mathcal{D}_X} R[t^{-1}].$. That is a flat degeneration over the Rees family from $\mathcal{M}$ to some module over $grA$.

Now if it were the case that "flat degenerations" still respect (coherent sheaf) $K$-theory in this setting one could conclude that any $\mathcal{D}_X$ module which has a good filtration gives $[\mathcal{M}]$ a well defined class in $K(T^*X)$. So my question is (slightly generalized form of the above):

> **Question:** Let $A$ be a flat associative noetherian $k[t]$-algebra with a regular commutative fiber over $0$. Let $M$ and $N$ be two finite type $A$-modules whose generic fibers are isomorphic (as $A[t^{-1}]$-modules). Do $M$ and $N$ define the same class in the (coherent) $K$ theory of the $0$ fiber $K(A \otimes_{k[t]} k)$?

Then the obvious generalization in the context of $D$-modules will be:

> Does the above give rise to a globally well defined canonical map between $K$-theory of coherent $\mathcal{D}$-modules and $\mathbb{C}^\times$-equivariant $K$-theory of the cotangent bundle? $$K(\mathcal{D}_X-mod) \to K_{\mathbb{C}^\times}(T^*X)$$ when
>   $X$ is a smooth complex algebraic variety?

Comment: Have you looked at Ginsburg's paper "Characteristic varieties and vanishing cycles"? Specifically, sections 1.1-1.3.